# Shipping a huge amount of logs from an unmanagable folder structure using filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elastic-beats

I am trying to ship log files to logstash using filebeat. The folder structure of the input path is currently very branchy and very big.
We have a following structure:

```
<LOG_PATH>/<STREAM>/<WORKFLOW>/<TASK>/<EXECUTION_DATE>/<TRY_NUMBER>.log
```

The logs are actually not that big, but the application produces every day an average of 300.000 new log files, depending on which workflows are running and which tasks. Every newly created log creates a new execution_date folder containing the log file, and at the end, we are having an unmanageable structure. A 'find' through the folder can take a week or more, and a 'ls' in some workflow folders can take hours. I even wrote a python script to count the files and task folders using glob, but the execution was terminated after some time.

As I could find out, filebeat is using filepath/glob, so my question is: how does filebeat "walk" through the input? can it be comparable to pythons glob, so that it just terminates after some time without any error log? can I assume that filebeat just can't handle this amount of files, under a shared volume?

If it's relevant, the application from which I try to collect the logs is Airflow.

Comment: Sorry I did not get the question?
Is the question can filebeat handle these many log files?

Comment: In some way, Yes. But in the meantime we have come to a conclusion that the underlying volume structure is the problem, because even a "ls" can take some time or even fail. So what we trying now, is to create subvolumes to solve the issue with the performance, and then we will try to collect the logs with filebeat again.